# POST request to Azure Functions App to be send twice before success in React (Axios, Fetch)

Tags: reactjs, axios, azure-functions

I have a simple upload form which onsbubmit should post data to API. In my previous question I struggled to get it running in general, but now CORS went into play. After spending hours on configuring CORS back an forth on Azure Function I got stuck. Finally I managed to verify the server with Curl (Allow Access Origin is matching). This made me thinking there is a bug/feature in how axios handles the requests. So I used fetch just before axios. When deployed one POST fire was successful. I thought I found the problem - so I commented out the axios part. Deployed again. Nothing. So I am back with the working solution but really dirty - one of the methods is firing Error. The other is working. I think the working one is the second one. Any ideas what is happening here?

Here is my code snippet:

```
formHandler() {
    const { formFields } = this.state;
    console.log(formFields);
    const response = fetch('https://example.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(formFields),
    })
    axios({
      url: 'https://example.com',
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      data: formFields

      }).then(function(response){
       console.log(response);

       //Perform action based on response
   })
     .catch(function(error){
      alert(error);
       console.log(error.status);
       //Perform action based on error
     });

  }
}
```

and this is the function.json content on Azure:

```
{ "bindings": [ { "authLevel": "function", "type": "httpTrigger", "direction": "in", "name": "req" }, { "type": "http", "direction": "out", "name": "res" } ] }
```

I have enabled the methods in the platform features of Azure Function. Should this automatically propagate to function.json? Or should I add this manually?

Comment: Can you edit the question to add your azure function code and information about your configuration like what is in your `function.json` file? It's likely something in the mating between Axios and Azure Functions - I've had some issues in the past, but have been able to successfully get it to work.

Comment: this is the function JSON from Azure Function:

Comment: {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You should configure your Azure Function's CORS to `*` until you get this completely figured out. Here's [how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors).

Comment: I didn't have to set any headers either, so I would recommend removing the headers field. Make sure your using `https` in the URL. Azure Functions App's bulk at `http` and respond as `GET` requests.

Comment: In your `url: 'https://example.com'`, you need to include the API key using a URL parameter (eg: `https://example.com?code=<MY_AZURE_FUNCTION_API_KEY>`.  You can read more about generating and including the key in the URL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=csharp#authorization-keys).

Comment: Ofcourse I have it. "example.com" is just a replacement for security reasons. The function is well tested with postman and it works. Plus as I wrote above one of the methods work - so it is jus the CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Axios sends an `OPTIONS` request prior to sending the `POST`. It's likely that the Azure Function is denying the `OPTIONS` request, which prevents the `POST` request from being successful. Read more about the `OPTIONS` verb [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572637/1913185). However, it looks like your function.json is missing a `methods` key that should have a value of `[ "options", "get", "post" ]`. This will explicitly allow both `OPTIONS` and `POST` (as well as `GET`).

Your Azure Function's `function.json` should be something like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "options",
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I just edited my question to address the "allowed methods" issue. Do you suggest I ignore the "platform features" blade and just edit the function.json?

Comment: Do you deploy through VS Code or directly in the cloud editor on the Azure Portal?

Comment: I worked directly in the portal copying and pasting for reference and local save into VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who struggle with similar issue the workaround is relatively simple. Stick to content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and avoid custom headers, this way it will not force preflight with OPTIONS.
There seems to be a bug either in Axios package and/or Azure Functions on handling posting/responding to OPTIONS call. Check out: https://medium.com/@praveen.beatle/avoiding-pre-flight-options-calls-on-cors-requests-baba9692c21a

for some other related hints.

In firefox I noticed that Option call from Localhost has Origin: null. This maybe AXIOS bug and Azure Function does not accept this call as proper Options call. But I stopped further investigation on his.